# azuredevops test code coverage result issues

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, microsoft-fakes

I have a .net framework project and a test project in my solution ,when i ran the test,the code coverage result showed reasonable.But we I use azuredevops pipeline to run the tests and get code coverage result,It is different from local resut,some extra dll displayed on the result board.

[image]

I used some fake dlls and it seems that these dlls come from fakes dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I should specify the runsettings files and config include and exclude in the pipeline,the issues will be solved.

```
 <Configuration>
          <CodeCoverage>
            <!-- Match assembly file paths: -->
            <ModulePaths>
              <Include>
                <ModulePath>.*FunctionApp*.dll</ModulePath>
                <!--<ModulePath>.*\.exe$</ModulePath>-->
              </Include>
              <Exclude>
                <ModulePath>.*AutoGenerated.dll</ModulePath>
                <ModulePath>.*Tests.dll</ModulePath>
              </Exclude>
            </ModulePaths>

            <!-- We recommend you do not change the following values: -->
            <UseVerifiableInstrumentation>True</UseVerifiableInstrumentation>
            <AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>True</AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>
            <CollectFromChildProcesses>True</CollectFromChildProcesses>
            <CollectAspDotNet>False</CollectAspDotNet>

          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
```

and in the pipeline,specify the settings

```
steps:
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'VsTest - testAssemblies'
  inputs:
    runSettingsFile: src/...../CodeCoverage.runsettings
```